# how can we compare two array values with same index in codeigniter

Tags: arrays, codeigniter

Here  i want to compare two array results where the results looks like this,`array1` looks like this

```
array(7) { [0]=> string(6) "M" [1]=> string(7) "T" [2]=> string(9) "W" [3]=> string(8) "T" [4]=> string(6) "F" [5]=> string(8) "S" [6]=> string(6) "S" }
```

`array2` looks like this

```
array(7) { [0]=> string(5) "15:00" [1]=> string(5) "14:00" [2]=> string(5) "13:00" [3]=> string(0) "" [4]=> string(5) "12:00" [5]=> string(5) "11:00" [6]=> string(5) "10:00" }
```

here i want to compare the `first value` of `array1` with the `first value` of `array2`row with the second and if the value return true it should perform a function and if the value return empty it should perform another function

so i had done my code like this

```
<?php foreach($array1 as $index => $val)
{
    foreach($array2 as $index2 => $val2){?>
    //here i want to compare $val with $val2 to check $val2 is not empty or not
    <?php }
}?>
```

Comment: and what will be the comparing criteria? means sunday compares to 13:00 how?

Comment: monday should compare with 15:00 and tuesday should compare with 14:00 and so on

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like that:

```
$array1 = array("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday");
$array2 = array("15:00","14:00","13:00","", "12:00","11:00","10:00");

foreach($array1 as $index => $val) {
    echo "compare $val to $array2[$index]  <br />";   
}
```

This code returns:

```
    compare Monday to 15:00 
    compare Tuesday to 14:00 
    compare Wednesday to 13:00 
    compare Thursday to 
    compare Friday to 12:00 
    compare Saturday to 11:00 
    compare Sunday to 10:00
```